# double pointer reference in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

This may a stupid question, but I'm gonna ask it anyway:

Suppose you have a pointer: `Object* pointer`  which points at a dynamically allocated object.

```
class PointClass
{
 Array<Object*> m_array1;
 Array<Object*> m_array2;

 void Delete1()
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < m_array1.Length; i++)
     {
         delete m_array1[i];
     }
 }

void Delete2()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_array2.Length; i++)
    {
        delete m_array2[i];
    }
 }
}
```

Now, you put your pointer both in `m_array1` and in `m_array2`.

When you try to delete the arrays, in one of them you will have a pointer which points to a deallocated space, so you can't delete it again!

I can't just assign the pointers NULL after the deletion because it wouldn't affect the pointer in the other array.

How would you solve it?

Comment: Fix your code: what is `m_array` and why is it being deleted in both Delete1() and Delete2() ?

Comment: Are you intending for the object to be deleted on the first pass or on the second pass?

Comment: I don't care, as long as it will be deleted. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the simplest way would be to use a reference-counting pointer, like those available in [boost::smart_ptrs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm).

Otherwise, you need to assign *owners* to the pointers - you need to decide which class will be responsible for allocating/deleting that particular pointer.  If for some reason you decide that should be *this* class, then you could remove the duplicates from the arrays by adding all the pointers to a [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/) before enumerating them.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to share pointers in this way, something like a ref counted pointer may work well.

See this site which gives an exposé of various 'smart-pointer' techniques. 
[Smart Pointers](http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/smart-pointers.html)

Answer (score 1):

My initial answer is: Don't do that.

If you absolutely have to for some reason, you could wrap it in a [smart pointer](http://ootips.org/yonat/4dev/smart-pointers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Best solved is not passing the same pointer to both arrays. :P If you really need to, and you also need to reflect that change to all other "same" pointers, a pointer-to-pointer will do.

```
#include <iostream>
struct Object{};

int main(){
  Object* ptr = new Object;
  Object** ptrptr = &ptr;
  delete *ptrptr;
  *ptrptr = 0;
  // both print 0
  std::cout << *ptrptr << std::endl;
  std::cout << ptr << std::endl;
}
```

[On Ideone](http://ideone.com/nMUHC).
Another way is with a reference-to-pointer.

```
int main(){
  Object* ptr = new Object;
  Object*& refptr = ptr;
  delete refptr;
  refptr = 0;
  // both print 0
  std::cout << refptr << std::endl;
  std::cout << ptr << std::endl;
}
```

But the second best way is probably a ref-counted smart pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> How would you solve it?

By not storing the same pointer in two different places.  Doing this creates a duplication of data, and confuses ownership semantics.  Who owns the memory pointed to by `pointer`?  Ownership is not clear.

Under normal circumstances, dynamically allocated objects should be owned by the same module that allocated it, and only that module will have direct access to the objects or delete the memory.  That's not to say other modules can't get at the data.

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested use smart pointers to solve your problem. If you have to solve it by writing your own code, I would make each of the delete function also search the "other" array to delete all pointers in the first array that can be found in the other array. And it is a last option option as this would not be my first solution to implement anything as your approach

```
void Delete2()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_array2.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m_array1.Length; j++)
        {
            if (m_array2[i] == m_array1[j])
            {
               delete m_array1[j]
               m_array1[j] = NULL;
            }

            delete m_array2[i];
            m_array2[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Then look for ways to optimise it

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question, you have the same (valid) pointer stored in 2 different arrays.

The problem is that after you delete it on array1, you can't do it again in the second array.

One way to do this is change your array definition to store the memory address of the pointer itself, instead of storing the address of the allocated memory:

```
const int array_size = 3;
int** m_array1[array_size];
int** m_array2[array_size];
```

and the rest of the code could be implemented as:

```
void Delete1()
{
     for (int i = 0; i < array_size - 1; i++) // delete all memory but leave the last intact
     {
         if (*(int*)m_array1[i])
         {
             cout << "Delete1: erasing #" << i << " with mem addr " << std::hex << *m_array1[i] << std::dec << endl;
             delete *m_array1[i];
             *m_array1[i] = NULL;
         }
     }
}

void Delete2()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        if (*m_array2[i])
        {
            cout << "Delete2: erasing #" << i << " with mem addr " << std::hex << *m_array2[i] << std::dec << endl;
            delete *m_array2[i];
            *m_array2[i] = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Delete2: !!! memory at #" << i << " was already deleted." << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int* num1 = new int(10);
    int* num2 = new int(20);
    int* num3 = new int(30);

    cout << "main: storing " << std::hex << &num1 << " which points to " << num1 << std::dec << endl;
    cout << "main: storing " << std::hex << &num2 << " which points to " << num2 << std::dec << endl;
    cout << "main: storing " << std::hex << &num3 << " which points to " << num3 << std::dec << endl;

    m_array1[0] = &num1;
    m_array1[1] = &num2;
    m_array1[2] = &num3;

    m_array2[0] = &num1;
    m_array2[1] = &num2;
    m_array2[2] = &num3;

    Delete1();
    Delete2();
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
main: storing 0xbfc3818c which points to 0x87b6008
main: storing 0xbfc38188 which points to 0x87b6018
main: storing 0xbfc38184 which points to 0x87b6028
Delete1: erasing #0 with mem addr 0x87b6008
Delete1: erasing #1 with mem addr 0x87b6018
Delete2: !!! memory at #0 was already deleted.
Delete2: !!! memory at #1 was already deleted.
Delete2: erasing #2 with mem addr 0x87b6028
```

Comment: This will not work, changing `m_array1[i]` does not change `m_array2[i]`

Comment: Exactly what @BlueRaja said. You've stumbled on the problem here; that you'd have to a) remember the address to delete and b) search `m_array2` for that address, removing that element.

Comment: @Idov Please test this approach.

Comment: @BlueRaja @Ninefingers Gentlemen, please review your comments and votes.